# Incorrect string value: '\x9C\x94\xBAw4\x9C...' for column 'pic_byte' at row 1 error

Tags: sql, spring, post, utf-8, byte

I am trying to send a post request with an image however I keep getting the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\x9C\x94\xBAw4\x9C...' for column 'pic_byte' at row 1
```

One solution I found was to convert from UTF8 to UTF8MB4 using the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE database.table MODIFY COLUMN col VARCHAR(255)  
    CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL;
```

However i still got the same error. below is my post method if that helps :

```
    @PostMapping("/upload")
public ResponseEntity.BodyBuilder uploadImage(@RequestParam("imageFile") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {

    System.out.println("Original Image Byte Size - " + file.getBytes().length);
    model img = new model(file.getOriginalFilename(), file.getContentType(),
            compressBytes(file.getBytes()));
    userRepository.save(img);
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

How would I go about fixing this? would I need to set some specific configurations in my application.properties file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the start of a character encoded with four bytes.

```
alter table `tablename`
modify column col VARCHAR(255
CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NULL ;
```

Comment: What version of mysql you are using?

Comment: Use this dependency.

Comment: <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.23</version>
</dependency>